# Receiving and sending DMX signals

Tags: gpio, midi

I've got a Showtec Showmaster 24 in school. Because this device is limited to control only 12 channels over DMX (without using scenes 24), I want to expand this limit with a Raspberry Pi.
I found this device: http://www.bitwizard.nl/shop/DMX-interface-for-Raspberry-pi. Maybe it's possible to receive DMX Signals from the board, processing them somehow (for example, you could control different scenes with different assignments for the different sliders with your smartphone connected to an access point USB stick) and then sending a DMX signal to the DMX bus.
Do you think this is possible? Or should I use some form of library like http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/ and use the GPIO-Pins of the Raspberry Pi for receiving and sending DMX signals?

I also thought about using the MIDI Out of the board for getting the slider positions, but if I read the manual of the board correctly, only pressing flash buttons is sent to MIDI Out. Maybe I will also use a combination of both, because the selection of a program is not sent over DMX (you could use channels 1-12 as standard sliders and channels 13-24 as program sliders, but then the page ability - resulting in 48 instead of 12 possible programs - would be useless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some success has been reported in using my pigpio library to send DMX messages (I presume receive would also work).  However it's pretty much on the cusp of what you can do on the Pi with a software based serial link.

I'd be looking for a hardware based physical interface.

I suggest you contact user Arjan in the raspberrypi.org forums and ask for advice.  This may be his web-site.  http://www.raspberrypi-dmx.com/

Comment: Too bad, the link has gone :( Thanks for sharing, though!